# Bigtable from_service_account_json() not working

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I am trying to connect to Bigtable using a specific service account which I have created on IAM and downloaded the JSON into my folder containing my python code. I've given the service account Bigtable Administrator permissions.

```
client = bigtable.Client(project='tunnel-insight-2-0-dev-291100', admin=True)
```

This works.

```
client = bigtable.Client(project='tunnel-insight-2-0-dev-291100', admin=True).from_service_account_json("tunnel-insight-2-0-dev-291100-4494b00c4389.json")
```

This doesn't work. I'm getting "ValueError: Client is not an admin client."

Anyone know why from_service_account_json doesn't work like other Google Client Sdks?

Answer (score 2):

I reproduced your use case on my side and everyting worked as expected with Python 3.7.3.

```
pip3 install --upgrade google-cloud-bigtable


from google.cloud import bigtable

client = bigtable.Client(project='my-project', admin=True)
client
# <google.cloud.bigtable.client.Client at 0x7f1a2f3687f0>

client = bigtable.Client(project='my-project', admin=True).from_service_account_json("key.json")
client
#<google.cloud.bigtable.client.Client at 0x7f1a2f28ffd0>
```

**#Edit**

Does this code works for your?

```
import os
from google.cloud import bigtable

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] =  '/home/key.json'
client = bigtable.Client(project='my-project', admin=True)

print client._admin
print client.credentials.service_account_email
```

It seems to be an issue with the client library.

Or you can try :

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

from google.cloud import bigtable

key_path = "key.json"

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
     key_path, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])

client = bigtable.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id,admin=True)

print (client._admin)
```

[Authenticating with a service account key file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file)

Comment: I'm on Python 3.6.3, I also tried 3.8. I also upgraded the sdk as above, still doesn't work.

I've also assigned Bigtable Administrator permissions to the service account via the IAM page. 

Still getting "ValueError: Client is not an admin client."

Comment: Tried it on 3.7.3 same problem. Tried it on an AI Platform notebook, not working as well. Same error